# How to download network .har file from devtools automatically with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How to download network .har file from devtools automatically with python selenium

I need to download .har file from chrome devtools network if pytest failed. I find out article with chrome-har-capturer. But looks like it has no traceability, only one snapshot with the url I reached out. Thank you if you can share any solution.